# Advice for writing Client-Server based game

Tags: java, c++, applet

I'm thinking about writing a game which is based around a server, and several client programs connect to it. The game (very) basically consists of a list of items which a user can 'accept', which would remove it from the list on all connected computers (this needs to update very quickly).

I'm thinking about using a Java applet for the client since I would like this to be portable and run from a browser (mostly in Windows), as well as updating fast, and either a C++ or Java server running on Linux (currently just a home server, but possibly to go on a VPS).

A previous 'incarnation' of this game ran in a browser, and used PHP+mySQL for the backend, but this swamped the server quite a bit when several people connected (that was with about 8 people, this would eventually need to handle a lot more).
The users would probably all be in the same physical location (with the same public IP address), and the system would get several requests per second, all of which would require sending the list back to the clients.

Some computers may have firewall restrictions on them, so would you recommend  using HTTP traffic, a custom port, or perhaps through SSH or some existing protocol?

Could anyone suggest some tips (threading, multiple requests of one item?), tools, databases (mySQL?), or APIs which would help me get started on this project? I would prefer C++ for the backend as it would be faster, but using Java would allow me to reuse code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use C++ because of speed alone.  It is highly unlikely that the difference in performance will make a real difference to your game. (Your network is likely to cloud any performance difference, unless you have 10 GigE between the client and server)  I would use C++ or Java because you will get it working first using that language.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use C++, since the only Java I've done was on Android (need to learn swing now for the client).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a good networking API for c++ I always suggest [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It has the advantage of being platform independent, so you can compile a server for linux, windows etc. However, if you are not too familiar with c++ templates/boost the code can be a little overwhelming. Have a look, give it a try.

In terms of general advice. Given the description above, you seem to need a relatively simple server. I would suggest keeping it very basic, single threaded polling loop. Read a message from your connected clients (wait on multiple sockets), and respond appropriately. This eliminates any issue around multiple accesses to your list and other synchronization problems.

I might also suggest, before you re-write your initial incarnation. Try improving it, as you have stated:

> and the system would get several requests per second, all of which would require sending the list back to the clients.

Given that each request removes an item from this list, why not just inform your uses which item is removed, rather than sending the entire list over the network time and time again? If this list is of any significant size, this minor change will result in a large improvement.

Comment: I'll have a look at Boost, thanks. The problem with the old one was that I couldn't work out push, so I used polling which flooded apache with requests.

Comment: Also, would you recommend having a threaded loop for each client, or one for all of them?

Comment: I would recommend a single threaded loop, simply because you will not have to worry about the plethora of synchronization issues that come with a multithreaded server. I would switch to a threaded server only if the request of one client could hold up my thread long enough that it would have a detrimental effect on the needs of other clients. Based off your description this is not the case.